# Display only distinct values based on property in the markup in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this markup:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: package() ? package().Products() : []">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <li>
      <div>
        <img data-bind="attr: { src: ImageUrl, alt: 'ItemId_' + ItemId }">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve (in the markup if possible) is to display only distinct items based on the ItemId, so if there are multiple items with the same ItemId I'll display only one of them.

Is it possible to do that in the markup data-bind property?

Comment: This is a really broad post, more a to do than a question. Could you update the post and include enough JS to reproduce the issue, and include your current attempt + be specific about where the problem is? (Additionally, you tag with jQuery and ko-mapping, but the post doesn't have any related code?)

Comment: @Jeroen my question is if its possible to filter the results in the html markup, not in the JS. So, I'm looking for some guidance if that's possible, not asking for anything which needs to be done on js side but on the html side using knockout commands. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to filter for unique items in the HTML, and it isn't in keeping with good Knockout programming to put program logic into the HTML. Make a computed that collects the unique items and iterate over the computed.